# How to write such a number pattern problems in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, if given a number 3, the program will print

```
1
1 2 2
1 2 2 3 3 3
```

OK,what I have tried like this:

```
n = eval(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

a=1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,a+1):
        print(j," ",sep="",end="")
    a+=1
    print()
```

It will print like:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? You need to ask a specific question. Simply dumping what appears to be homework is inappropriate.

Comment: Do you have any code demonstrating what you've tried?

Comment: I'll show you mine if you show me yours...

Comment: chew on this `print(" ".join([y for x in ([str(i)]*i for i in range(1,4)) for y in x]))`

Comment: this only prints the last line of the expected output however :-p

Comment: @ChristianDean promises promises :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's a lot better now!

Comment: @ChristianDean LOL again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084911/what-is-the-working-rule-of-this-program-explanation

Comment: a lot better but too late... Better luck next time. good luck to you, there's actually a good chance of reopening. I've sent a reopen request to SOCVR

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's never to late! </joking>

Comment: thumbs up for reopening that one. It was a close call ... and they say SO is elitist and bashful. Proved them wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Your problem is that you need to use `j` to print the current number `j` times. Thankfully, Python makes this easy by using *sequence multiplication*. That is, Python allows you to multiply a sequence - like a string - by a number. The contents of the string is replicated the amount of times it was multiplied by:

```
>>> 'a' * 3
'aaa'
>>> '1' * 4
'1111'
```

Thus, you can convert the current integer `j` to a string, and multiplied the string by `j`:

```
for j in range(1, a + 1):
    print((str(j) + ' ') * j, sep='', end="")
```

With the above change your code now outputs:

```
Enter a positive integer:  3
1 
1 2 2 
1 2 2 3 3
```

Here are a few more ways you can improve your code.

- Avoid `eval` like the black plague. It's very dangerous security-wise. Of course, you probably don't even have to worry about this now, but better not get in the habit. There's always a Better Way <sup>TM</sup>. In this case, use the built-in function `int`.
- Rather than keeping an explicit counter with `a`, use the built-in function `enumerate`.

With the above improvements, your code becomes:

```
n = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

for a, i in enumerate(range(1, n + 1), 1):
    for j in range(1, a + 1):
        print((str(j) + ' ') * j, sep='', end="")
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me such great suggestion!

Comment: @WeizhengZhang Glad to help out :-)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a method that does what you're requesting.

```
def numbers(n: int) -> None:
    for i in range(1, n+2):
        for j in range(1, i):
            print(j * (str(j) + ' '), end='')
        print()
```

1. First, we loop over all numbers from 1 to `n+1`.
2. Then, we loop over all numbers from 1 to the current number we are working with, minus one (that's why we have the `n+2` in the outer loop).
3. Now we have all the information we need to print our line: we are printing `j` times the value of `j` followed by a space, appending it to whatever was printed on this line already before.
4. Finally, after finishing our line, we print a newline, so we can start fresh in the next outer loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I'm new here. Why is this? (I understand if this is not the space to discuss this).

I just thought it was a nice little puzzle, that's all. :-)

Comment: Don't encourage people who show no effort and expect work to be done for them. Especially when there's a good chance it's a homework problem.

Comment: it's not so bad, but probably has been asked before, and mostly, too broad. OP doesn't provide any directions on how to solve this or how he/she tried to solve this. well if the question is properly worded, it may get some upvotes/not that much downvotes, but not here.

Comment: now you can [edit] your post to show OP errors & explain your code. Code only answers, no way...

Comment: voilà! c'est fait! :-)

Comment: Actually I have found the answer according to your post. Just adding (j*(str(j) +" ")

Comment: ah, great! yes, you would have saved many people a lot of time if you would have provided your own code from the start. anyway, I'm happy your problem is solved. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a key thing in the code you've given (as below):

```
n = eval(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

a=1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,a+1):
        print(j," ",sep="",end="")
    a+=1
    print()
```

Within the `for j in range(...)` loop, where you actually print out each number, you only print the each number out once, rather than `j` times (where `j` is the current number).

You can fix this by using a special behavior of Python (string 'multiplication').

```
n = eval(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

a = 1
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, a+1):
        print('{} '.format(j) * j, end="")
        a += 1
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

You are definitely on the right track. Let's look closer at your code:

```
n = eval(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

a=1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,a+1):
        print(j," ",sep="",end="")
    a+=1
    print()
```

**i** is going iterate from 1 to **n**. That's a good intuition, as we need every number.

**j** is going iterate from 1 to **a**. A way to debug the code is to work through an example. Let's say **i** will iterate in range(1, 3). The first time in the loop, **j** will iterate in range(1, 2) and it'll print "1". The second time,  **j** will iterate in range(1, 3) and it'll print "1 2". There's our problem; we wanted 2 to print out twice!

**i** is actually the number we want to print, **j** is the number of times we want to print the number. We actually don't need the **a** variable:

```
n = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

message = "" 
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(0, i):
        message += str(i) + " "
    print(message)
```

We can condense this further. I try to think of it in my head first, and then code it.

"I want 1 once, 2 twice, 3 thrice, etc.". This means, we don't even need an inner loop. You know how many times you want to print **i**... **i** times!

```
message = ""
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    message += (str(i) + " ") * i
    print(message)
```

Also, notice the style in your code. PEP8 has guidelines for how to write proper Python code. Notice:

- Using "int" is better than "eval" if possible, because you only want your program to take numbers.
- Spacing in parenthesis "range(1, a+1)" is better than "range(1,a+1)".
- Variable declarations like "a = 1" is better than "a=1".

These best practices will make your code more readable :)

Answer (score -3):

```
>>> print(*[' '.join(map(str, [n for n in range(1, n+1) for n in [n]*n])) for n in range(1, n+1)], sep='\n')
1
1 2 2
1 2 2 3 3 3
```