# what is the working rule of this program, Explanation?

Tags: c

i am little confuse in this program i want if anyone could explain to me the functionality of this code and the output, i am getting the output of this program as such

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

All i want to know the working rule of that two functions how they calculating the values?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int M(const int n);
int F(const int n)
{
    return(n==0)?1:n-M(F(n-1));
}
int M(const int n)
{
    return (n==0)?0:n-F(M(n-1));
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        printf("%2d\n",F(i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run this code "by hand", tracking manually every recursive call and the call stack state?

Comment: I don't suppose the *author* has anything to say about this?

Comment: i tried i found this code on net , and when i calculated this in a paper i was getting different values, by the logic of recursion which i have with me @MatteoItalia

Comment: @ZubairNoor please post the link to where you found it - there may be more info there to help us.

Comment: If you already tried it on paper and didn't get the same results, next try it with a debugger to see exactly where it does something you didn't.

Comment: i tried that , but i need someone to explain to me more lightly then debugger ! @aschepler

Comment: What do you mean by "working rule"? In some cases it's possible to simplify things, but here the expressions involved seem pretty arbitrary so it may not be possible.

Comment: A debugger is designed to go through code line by line and show you exactly what is happening at each and every step. How could that not provide the information you are looking for?

Comment: @ZubairNoor 'i tried that' OK, so what exactly did you try with your debugger and what did you find out at each step?

Comment: @ZubairNoor you see, the thing is, we get a great many posters who copy code from homework, the net, or other students, and just dump it here for us to explain how it works so they can hand it in as an assignment without doing any real work themselves at all.  I'm sure that you are not one of those users, so please link the net page where you got the code so we can see what explanation/s there are there, and tell us what you found out with your debugger.

Comment: @MartinJames for the assignment , i don't post such a small code , look down to the answers of that two users , i just want to need such that answer how they break it out all those code in small portions for good understanding. if u can so please explain it like that. and yes i got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider on `for`

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    printf("%2d\n",F(i));
}
```

**Short answer:**

`F(0) => 1;`

`F(1)=> 1 - M(F(0))`

```
when  F(0):1 then F(1) = 1 - M(1)
go to calculate M(1), but we start from 0, M(0)= 0;
M(1) = 1- F(M(0)) = 1- F(0) = 1-1=0;
last we have M(1) = 0; and as F(1) = 1-M(1) = 1-0=1
last we have: F(1)=1
```

**More complete:**

Let see `F()` way of working.
the last command in `F()`, 
  `return(n==0)?1:n-M(F(n-1));`

expanded to

```
if (n==0){
 return 1;
}else{
   return n-M(F(n-1));
}
```

In first for iteration `i:0`, we want `F(0)` as n is zero, (`n:0`), the `if (n==0)` is true , `return 1;` is executed and value of`F(0)` have to be 1.

for second iteration we want `F(1)`, for that `if (n==0)` is false and else block is execute.

as now the `n:1`, `F(1) = 1 - M (F(0))`.

In previous iteration we have `F(0)=1`, OK now we can rewire or equation: `F(1) = 1 - M(1)`, it obvious that if we have value of `M(1)` simply , put it on to the last formula , `F(1)` have been solved.

for this we must expand `M()` function.

Similarly we can write for  `M()`.

```
if (n==0){
 return 0;
}else{
   return n-F(M(n-1));
}
```

`M(0) = 0;`

`M(1)= 1- F(M(0))= 1- F(0) = 1 - 1=0;`

now we have `M(1) = 0;` by putting it on the `F(1) = 1 - M(1)` 
we achieve to `F(1) = 1`.

Now the first two pair of `1` in output of your code is calculated by hand.

for others, do this way over and over.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments try to trace the code by hand, I will go through the first two iterations with you so you get the idea

When your program starts it calls your `main` function, and starts executing the for loop as follows:

```
i=0 => calls F(n=0) => is n==0 true? Yes => return 1 => print 1

i=1 => calls F(n=1) => is n==0 true? No => then 1-M(F(0)) => F(0) calculated from the previous iteration to return a value of 1 => call M(n=1) => is n==0 true? No => then 1-F(M(0)) => M(0) returns 0 since n==0 is true => then 1-F(M(0)) is equal to 1-F(0) => we calculated F(0) to return 1 => so 1-F(0) return 0 from M => take the return back to 1-M(F(0)) => 1-0 = 1 => print 1
```

Do not be frustrated because what you are asking would be actually much easier to understand with some patient. I extremely recommend that you hold down a pen and paper and start tracing yourself.

1. Go iteration by iteration as I did.
2. Call each function according to the correct flow of the if conditions.
3. When you call a function, mark where you have left in the code to jump to said function, such that once it returns a value, you know exactly where to place the returned value.

Peace of paper, patience, and trace.